# Difference in usage

Tags: verbs, verb-usage

Which one is correct,
"Wear  a  scarf, and you'll  look fashionable." or
"Put on a  scarf, and you'll  look fashionable." ?

Comment: Both are correct. Whichever one do you prefer?

Comment: Can you tell us what you mean by "correct" here?

Comment: Both are OK but mean different things. Do you understand the difference between "to wear" and "to put on"?

Comment: I know that "to put on" means the action itself to wear clothes, otherwise "to wear" means ' to be dressed in'. Am I right? So my question was that 'In the above sentence, can we use both of them interchangably in spite of the difference in meaning? Is it possible to use wear in an imperative sentence?

Answer (score 2):

Whilst either could be used in both situations, I would say that "Wear a scarf..." is slightly more impersonal advice about fashion in general; "Put on a scarf..." is more likely to be used as a direct instruction to someone who is not currently wearing a scarf, and should be.

Comment: *wear* could also be used regarding someone not wearing a scarf. For example: (Her) "But with this outfit I am not sure how I will look." (You) "Wear a scarf, and you'll look fashionable." as an advice on better appearance.